# The Contract Name 'MyCompany.CostReduction.EditInitiatives' could not found in the list of contract bt the service 'EditInitiatives'

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, wcf

I am getting above error for ajax based WCF serive. Code looks like below.

### Code

```
    <ServiceContract()>
    Public Interface IEditInitiatives
        <OperationContract()> _
       <WebInvoke(BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="GetGridData")> _
        Function GetGridData(session As String) As List(Of InitiativeData)    

        <OperationContract()> _
        <WebInvoke(Method:="POST", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
        Function SaveGridData(input As String) As String

    End Interface    
    <AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)>
    Public Class EditInitiatives
        Implements IEditInitiatives


        Function GetGridData(session As String) As List(Of InitiativeData) Implements IEditInitiatives.GetGridData
           'Business logice
        End Function

        Function SaveGridData(ByVal input As String) As String Implements IEditInitiatives.SaveGridData

            Return "ok"
        End Function

End Class
```

### Web.Config

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyCompany.CostReduction.EditInitiativesAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <enableWebScript/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="MyCompany.CostReduction.EditInitiatives" behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="MyCompany.CostReduction.EditInitiativesAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyCompany.CostReduction.IEditInitiatives" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="UsernameWithTransport">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Where is your InitiativeData definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a stab at it:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
```

Make sure you place those attributes on InitiativeData

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
```